# How to count the number of non-NaN columns in a row in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has 15 columns. Most of the columns are NaN. I would like to have a new column displaying how many NaN column is there in each row.

Input:

```
  0 1 3
a 1 4 NaN
b 2 5 7
c 3 6 NaN
```

Output:

```
  0 1 3    number_of_non_nans
a 1 4 NaN  2
b 2 5 7    3
c 3 6 NaN  2
```

Pandas has sum() but I was not sure how to apply to this. It seems it can only sum the actual values.

```
df_f['number_of_non_nans'] = df_f.sum(1, axis=1)
```

Is there a way to count non-NaNs?

Comment: You can apply a lambda with numpy  .isna() function to dataframe and tge sum by row or colums.

Comment: simply `df.count(axis=1)` should do the trick, it will only count True values.

Comment: Or df.isna()  pandas function

Comment: Combine with @Datanovice advice it should be df.isna().count(axis=1).

Comment: @Datanovice solution is complete.  Count only counts 'non-nan' values.  No need to add the isna infront.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use,

```
df['Number_of_non_nans'] = df.notna().sum(axis=1)
```

or as @Datanovice suggests in comments use:

```
 df['Number_of_non_nans'] = df.count(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
|    |   0 |   1 |   3 |   Number_of_non_nans |
|----|-----|-----|-----|----------------------|
| a  |   1 |   4 | nan |                    2 |
| b  |   2 |   5 |   7 |                    3 |
| c  |   3 |   6 | nan |                    2 |
```

### Timings:

> %timeit df.count(axis=1)

```
656 µs ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops
> each)
```

> %timeit df.isna().sum(axis=1)

```
> 437 µs ± 3.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```